# Cant get Jenkins to work with fastlane

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, rvm

I have a Jenkins server that pulls my build and builds it, in the shell scripts i have a fastlane command that runs by distribution. Issue is it never is able to execute sucessfully.

my shell code is simply:

```
bundle exec fastlane distribute_to_testflight
```

called as i use plugins for fastlane in my project.

Result:

```
 $ bash -c export
    $ bash -c "test -f ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
    $ bash -c "test -f ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
    [App] $ bash -c " source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use --install --create 2.4.1 && export > rvm.env"
    Using /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1
    [App] $ /bin/sh -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins2674080270342174416.sh
    + bundle exec fastlane distribute_to_testflight
    /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize': Could not find CFPropertyList-2.3.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `map!'
        from /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `materialize'
        from /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
        from /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
        from /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
        from /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
        from /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
        from /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
        from /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Im not sure of the issue, i installed ruby with rvm on the jenkins user as you can see, but in my main project i work on the code with, i just have my ruby gems and files in the actual project repo that i commit to git, so perhaps i could get jenkins to use what it pulls from the repo?

Im really lost on this so any guidance on the issue would be great

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by calling **bundle install**  prior to my **bundle exec** call:

```
bundle install 
bundle exec fastlane distribute_to_testflight
```

I then use the following **Fastlane** command at the top of my lane so from then on it should keep things up to date:

```
bundle_install()
```

Answer (score 0):

CFPropertyList-2.3.6 is a gem available in main ruby gem repo at: https://rubygems.org

So add or set in Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
```

then run

```
bundle install
```

and ensure your machine can go internet.